# After-submit anchor (with PHP)

Tags: php, forms, submit, reload

I have a big form with several tables, each of one calculates a sum (of price and quantity) and then there's one at the end that calculates the total.
The structure is, more or less, this:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="purchase_form">
    <div id="purchase_1">
        <table>
            <input id="price_1">
            <input id="quantity_1">

            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Click here to calculate the partial">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="purchase_2">
        <table>
            <input id="price_2">
            <input id="quantity_2">

            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Click here to calculate the partial">
        </table>
    </div>

    <tr>
        <td id="price_sum"><?php *script* ?></td>
        <td id="quantity_sum"><?php *script* ?></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Now, when I click on submit to calculate the "partial", it gives me the total, at the same time. I know it's not a *state-of-the-art* form, but anyway, just try to turn a blind eye on that.

What I want is, when I click on submit button, to have the page reloaded showing the form I have clicked on. Like, if I click on submit of the #purchase_1 table, I want the page to reload on #purchase_1 table, and so on.

Is there a trick?

Comment: looks like you can try `ajax`

Comment: Yeah, I could, but it would be a big work, and then there are some things I'm not sure would work. Whenever the user has finished to calculate the pieces and the prices, he's sent to another page where there is a recap of the purchase and where he's filling up a form with personal info.

Comment: very easy using javascript, very complex using only php (but still possible :-)

Comment: You mean it's simple even with the second page (in which there are the purchased elements of the first page plus a personal info form, and everything gets sent by email when the user clicks on submit)?

Comment: p.s. I know it's pretty complicated, but it's a work I've done a few years ago, and to be honest I don't even use PHP anymore - but I was hoping to do this, at least, without having to change everything.